# How to test Forward Euler implementation

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I have written some C++ code to implement FE method. I am looking for a simple free software that I can use to test accuracy of my implementation. Do scilab/octave implement this method?

Comment: Compute approximations for the same exact value with various small step sizes. The result should be a straight line. You can estimate the error via Richardson extrapolation. Then a loglog plot should also show a straight line with slope one.